# Tensorflow ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Today I was working on a sign language detector using deep learning by `Tensorflow`

And by following the tutorial named [Training Custom Object Detector](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html)  but as soon as I get to the training stage it gives me this Error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (C:\Python\379\lib\site-packages\object_detection\__init__.py)
```

And also in this below Image [image]

It says to put the `model_main_tf2.py` in the `training_demo` folder but then `model_main_tf2.py` can't import the classes because they are all local classes take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmwC9.png)

**I am new to this so please help**
**If you want any other info **Please Ask****

***Thanks!!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error looks like this,
`ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (C:\Python\379\lib\site-packages\object_detection\__init__.py)`.

Clearly, python is unable to find **model_lib_v2.py** at "C:\Python\379\lib\site-packages\object_detection" since that particular file is located in another directory (as shown in the image attached by you).

You need to check your working directory and set working directory to the path as shown in **your attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmwC9.png)**.

Comment: Currently I am on another machine So when I am home I will check this out : BTW thanks for the reply